# How do i make Google+ to SignOut from other Activity?

Tags: android, google-plus

Well i have created a Google+ Signin successfully.
And i'm trying to signout the g+ from the other activity.

I tried the below code it's not working as per my expectation.
what I wanted is the app signin from LoginActivity & signout from MainActivity.

Below is my LoginActivity Code.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
//import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
//import android.content.CursorLoader;
//import android.content.Loader;

/**
 * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnClickListener, com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

      /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
      private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

      /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
      public static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

      /* A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents
       * us from starting further intents.
       */
      private boolean mIntentInProgress;

      /* Track whether the sign-in button has been clicked so that we know to resolve
       * all issues preventing sign-in without waiting.
       */
      private boolean mSignInClicked;

      /* Store the connection result from onConnectionFailed callbacks so that we can
       * resolve them when the user clicks sign-in.
       */
      private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    /**
     * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
     * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
     */
    private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[] {
            "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world" };
    /**
     * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
     */
    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mLoginFormView;



        @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
         mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

        /*
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
              mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
    }
*/

    public void disconnect(){
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.e("LoginActivity()","before signout" + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
              mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
              Log.e("LoginActivity()","after signout" + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

         mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();

        /* Button signin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
         signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                        mSignInClicked = true;
                        resolveSignInErrors();
                      }
            }
        }); */

         findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

         Button signout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signout_in_button);
         signout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Log.e("LoginActivity()","before signout" + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
                 if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                      Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                      mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                      mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    }
                 Log.e("LoginActivity()","After signout" + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
            }
        });

        // Set up the login form.
        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        populateAutoComplete();

        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mPasswordView
                .setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id,
                            KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                        if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                            attemptLogin();
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

        Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
        mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
    }

    //result.getResolution().getIntentSender()
    /* A helper method to resolve the current ConnectionResult error. */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
    //  if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
          mIntentInProgress = true;
          startIntentSenderForResult(mConnectionResult.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
              RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
          // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
          // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
          mIntentInProgress = false;
          mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    //  }
    }

    private void populateAutoComplete() {
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            // Use ContactsContract.Profile (API 14+)
            //getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        } else if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
            // Use AccountManager (API 8+)
            new SetupEmailAutoCompleteTask().execute(null, null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    public void attemptLogin() {
        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Reset errors.
        mEmailView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
            // perform the user login attempt.
            showProgress(true);
            mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
            mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        }
    }

    private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        // TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return email.contains("@");
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        // TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return password.length() > 4;
    }

    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    public void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                    .alpha(show ? 0 : 1)
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE
                                    : View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });

            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                    .alpha(show ? 1 : 0)
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE
                                    : View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY),
                ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?",
                new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE },

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }

    private interface ProfileQuery {
        String[] PROJECTION = { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY, };

        int ADDRESS = 0;
        int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
    }

    /**
     * Use an AsyncTask to fetch the user's email addresses on a background
     * thread, and update the email text field with results on the main UI
     * thread.
     */
    class SetupEmailAutoCompleteTask extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            ArrayList<String> emailAddressCollection = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Get all emails from the user's contacts and copy them to a list.
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, null);
            while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                String email = emailCur
                        .getString(emailCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                emailAddressCollection.add(email);
            }
            emailCur.close();

            return emailAddressCollection;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
            addEmailsToAutoComplete(emailAddressCollection);
        }
    }

    private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
        // Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its
        // dropdown list.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                LoginActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                emailAddressCollection);

        mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private final String mEmail;
        private final String mPassword;

        UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

            try {
                // Simulate network access.
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return false;
            }

            for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
                String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
                if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                    // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                    return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
                }
            }

            // TODO: register the new account here.
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success) {
                finish();
            } else {
                mPasswordView
                        .setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if (!mIntentInProgress) {
                // Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks
                // 'sign-in'.
                mConnectionResult = result;

                if (mSignInClicked) {
                  // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
                  // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                    resolveSignInError();
                }
              }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
          //TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                  mSignInClicked = false;
                }

                mIntentInProgress = false;

                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                  mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
              }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mSignInClicked = false;
         Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Log.e("LoginActivity()","onconnected status :" + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
         Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
         LoginActivity.this.startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button
                && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mSignInClicked = true;
                resolveSignInError();
              }
    }
}
```

And Layout for this activity_login.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dotncube.gmailtest.LoginActivity" >

    <!-- Login progress -->

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <Button
                android:id="@+id/signout_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Signout from google"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in MainActivity I'm calling signout function of LoginActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void signout(View v){
        LoginActivity obj = new LoginActivity();
        obj.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What does "sign out" mean to you?  Should the user expect to re-select their account?  Or do you want to completely deauthorize your app so the next time they use it they'll see the account picker and sign-in dialog?

If you just want them to see the account picker next time, call `Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(...)`.  If you want your app deauthorized, call `Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(...)` and wait for the response.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Account.html